# Como evitar a duplicação de conteudo em uma tabela sem chave primária?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-2

Em um painel de loja virtual que estou construindo os produtos tem relações por cor e tamanho, onde cada cor de produto tem um tamanho.
Esta é uma parte do meu banco de dados para melhor entendimento do problema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0dee
Quando o usuário quer associar as cores a um produto no painel ele é encaminhado a uma página com todas as cores (lista de *checkbox*) e nesta ele seleciona as cores e envia o formulário ao [php](/questions/tagged/php) que processa com o seguinte *script*:
Obs.: `$database` é uma instancia do [Doctrine DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html#version2.5)

```
$checking = [];
$colors   = (array) $_POST['colors'];

$ids = [];
foreach($colors as $color) if(is_numeric($color)) $ids[]=$color;

$emptyTableQuery = $database->createQueryBuilder();
$emptyTableQuery -> delete('product_colors')
                 -> where('id_product = :idProduct AND id_color NOT IN (:ids)')
                 -> setParameters([':idProduct'=>$id,':ids'=>implode(',',$ids)]);

$emptyTable = $emptyTableQuery->execute();

foreach($colors as $color)
    $checking[] = $database->insert(
        'product_colors',
        [
            'id_product'=> $id,
            'id_color'=> $color
        ],
        ['id_product'=>\PDO::PARAM_INT,'id_color'=>\PDO::PARAM_INT]
        );
```

Quando um produto novo é inserido o código funciona perfeitamente, porém, quando as cores do produto são atualizadas as cores já existentes no banco de dados são duplicadas...

> Antes do código atual TODAS as cores eram removidas da tabela, ou
>   seja, ela era completamente limpa, o que me resultou em um problema
>   maior: existe uma terceira relação com a tabela chamada
>   'sizes_by_product_color' onde estão guardados os tamanhos para cada
>   cor e os respectivos estoques, ou seja, se eu deletasse tudo também
>   eram perdidos estes dados e o cliente teria de cadastrar todos os
>   tamanhos para as cores, antes existentes, novamente...

Esta é uma parte do meu banco de dados para melhor entendimento do problema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0dee

Como eu poderia resolver meu problema de forma prática? existe alguma solução para o SQL ou eu terei de fazer um select para fazer a verificação no PHP?

Comment: Não entendi porque duplica, já que você ta excluindo os dados iguais antes de inserir..

Comment: Então @lúcio-rubens, antes eu excluía todas as cores para o produto (e consequentemente seus dados) e funcionava, mas o problema era que eu perdia os dados que o usuário queria que fossem mantidos, com o código atual, eu mantenho os dados que o usuário não mexeu (com o `id_color NOT IN (:ids)` da linha 9), porém é tudo inserido novamente, duplicando conteúdo. (ex.: foi selecionada a cor 1 e ela já existe na tabela, então ela não é excluida no '$emptyTableQuery', porém ela é reescrita no `insert` da linha 15...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho muita experiência em PHP, mas tenho em SQL, então vou compartilhar minha opinião:

No seu código, ao salvar um produto, todas as cores de um produto que não estão presentes na lista selecionada são removidas do banco. Depois, relações entre produto e cor são adicionadas para cada cor selecionada.

Isso vai funcionar sempre da primeira vez, uma vez que não há cores relacionadas a um produto, então não há chance de conflito.
Entretando, ao atualizar um produto que já possua relações com cores, você estará tentando inserir cores repetidas. Veja:

```
$id = 1;

-INSERÇÂO:
$colors = {"#000000","#FFFFFF"};

    -REMOÇÃO DE product_color ONDE product_id = $id E color_id NÃO ESTEJA EM $colors:
    Nada é feito. Não existem registros em product_color com product_id = $id 
    -ADIÇÃO DE UM product_color PARA CADA $colors:
    product_colors = 
    product_id | color_id
        1      | "#000000"
        1      | "#FFFFFF"

-ATUALIZAÇÃO:  
$colors = {"#000000","#112233"};    

    -REMOÇÃO DE product_color ONDE product_id = $id E color_id NÃO ESTEJA EM $colors:
    product_id | color_id
        1      | "#000000"

    -ADIÇÃO DE UM product_color PARA CADA $colors:
    product_colors = 
    product_id | color_id
        1      | "#000000" <-- Já existia e não foi deletado!
        1      | "#000000" 
        1      | "#112233"
```

A solução mais fácil que eu consigo pensar é, ao invés de deletar somente as cores que não foram selecionadas em product_colors, deletar todas. Elas serão inseridas novamente na instrução seguinte, de qualquer forma.

Se não quiser fazer isso, provavelmente você não vai escapar de selecionar as cores existentes no produto após o delete e inserir somente as cores que não constarem na lista.

**Edição:** Após alguma pesquisa, cheguei a conclusão de que a recomendação geral é mesmo checar consultar o banco para checar quais cores já estão relacionadas ao produto e não inseri-las. Em teoria, seria possível utilizar a clausula `INSERT IGNORE` do MySql caso você pudesse marcar ambas as colunas como `UNIQUE`, mas pelo que li, o Doctrine não possui uma representação para esta função (o que é compreensível, uma vez que ele é um componente para abstrair o DB, e não uma implementação específica de MySql).
Minhas referências principais foram [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21591092/4905310), [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23501727/4905310) e [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2271026/4905310), caso esteja interessado em se aprofundar nas razões expostas. Todos os links são para o SO em inglês.

Comment: obrigado pela reposta, mas existe um pequeno problema em eu deletar todas as cores da tabela: existe uma terceira relação chamada 'sizes_by_product_color' onde estão guardados os tamanhos para cada cor e os respectivos estoques, ou seja, se eu deletar tudo eu perco também estes dados e o cliente vai ter de cadastrar tudo novamente... =/

Comment: Bem, como o `INSERT IGNORE` funciona apenas para PK's não vai funcionar no meu caso onde as FK's estão sendo duplicadas e uma nova PK esta sendo gerada para a relação, ou seja, infelizmente vou ter de fazer um `SELECT` para a checagem... Obrigado pela ajuda e esforço!

Comment: Funciona na verdade para qualquer CONTRAINT UNIQUE. Mas sim, acabei esquecendo de colocar que esta opção só seria considerada caso você pudesse adicionar tal CONSTRAINT em ambas as colunas. Editado.